# Trouble with children pushing each other out of a box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to dynamically display some List items by letting users enter strings into an input bar.

on submit, JS will show:

- checkbox
- String entered by user
- button to delete entered string

I gave the checkbox and the button id's, but js won't allow me to give the user entered string an id (text can't have an id). The problem arises when I enter a large string, it starts to push the other two list item children out of the container.

How can I set a max amount of space for the user entered text?

(there are some typescriptadditions in the JS code)

```js
function todoList() {

    // turn the input text into variable:
    const item: string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('todoInput')).value;


    // Create text-node:
    const text = document.createTextNode(item);


    // Create list item:
    const newItem = document.createElement('li');


    // Create button:
    const button: any = document.createElement("button");
    button.id="button";

    // Create button text node and append it to button:
    const btnText = document.createTextNode('Delete');
    button.appendChild(btnText);

    // Add handler to actually delete the entry:
    button.addEventListener("click", (e: any) => {
        newItem.remove();
    });


    // create checkbox and give it id and name
    const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type="checkbox";
    checkbox.id="checkbox";
    checkbox.name="form-checkbox";


    // Append text,checkbox and button to the list item:
    newItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    newItem.appendChild(text);
    newItem.appendChild(button);

    // Append list item to the ordered list:
    // @ts-ignore
    document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);


}

const form = (document.getElementById('todoForm'))
// @ts-ignore
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // resets input field to blank after user submits task
    const resetInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('todoInput')
    resetInput.value = '';

})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
body{
    font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

}


.title{
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);

}



#todoForm{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    width: 30rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 3px #cdcaca;

}

#scrolldown-menu-toggle{
    border-width: 0;
    width: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #b6adad;
    opacity: 1;
}

#todoInput{
    width: 95%;
    border-width: 0;
    font-size: 130%;

}
#todoInput:focus{
    outline: none;
}

::placeholder {
    color: #b6adad;
    opacity: 1;
}


#todo-input select:focus{
    outline: none !important;
  /*  ik wil dat bij het selecteren de border niet gehighlight wordt*/
}

li{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    width: 30rem;
    max-width: 30rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 3px #cdcaca;
    background: white;
    align-items: start;
    font-size: 130%;
    min-width: 0;
    gap: 20px;
}


#checkbox {
    width: 1.3rem;
    height: 1.3rem;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}
#checkbox:checked {
    background-color: #b3cbb2;
}


#button{
    background: red;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: fit-content;


}

.info{
    margin-top: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>To do list</title>
</head>
<body>



<h1 class="title">todos</h1>
<form id="todoForm" onsubmit="todoList()" >
    <button  id="scrolldown-menu-toggle">˅</button>
    <input type="text" id="todoInput" placeholder="Fill in your plan">
</form>


<ol id="todoList">
</ol>


<footer class="info">
    <p>Double click to edit a todo.</p>
    <p>Created by Thomas Brom.</p>
</footer>


<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. You should fix your snippet so that it runs: > SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration.

Comment: "*js won't allow me to give the user entered string an id (text can't have an id)*" why is this relevant at all? Why would you even try to give ID to a string? And why is JS even relevant - seems just like a CSS question for how to display stuff without the layout being broken by long strings. Or should the layout be governed by JS?

Comment: If a string is too large to take care then the string should be split by two to be handled.

Comment: If it could be solved by using just css then that would be fine too. but i fail to see the way to keep the three list item children in their position with css (thats the big problem really)

Answer (score 0):

Use the maxlength attribute on you're html input tag like this :

```html
<input type="text" id="todoInput" placeholder="Fill in your plan" maxlength='12'>
```

or Just append the input text inside a paragraph tag and give the p tag a max-width and hide the overflow.